# Create pandas dataframe : map a function over numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am create a pandas dataframe and using numpy to simulate values. I'd like to assign randomly generated ids to two columns in pandas, for which, I wrote a function that returns alphanumeric ids.

However, with my current code, it only calls the function once and returns same ids for all rows. I need unique ids for each row and therefore need to efficiently iterate over pandas dataframe.

Ideally, `.apply` does this, however, I need this to be done when I create the pandas dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
# Generate alphanumeric lease id and property ids
def gen_ids(length):
    
    ids = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=length))

    return ids

# Create DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'LeaseID': gen_ids(10)
                   'PropertyID': gen_ids(10),
                   'xyz': np.random.choice(List1, 1000),  
                   'abc': np.random.choice(List2, 1000),
                 })
```

Result:

[image: pandas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call get_ids once for every cell, and not once for every column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'LeaseID': [gen_ids(10) for _ in range(1000)], 
                   'PropertyID': [gen_ids(10) for _ in range(1000)],
                   'xyz': np.random.choice(List1, 1000),  
                   'abc': np.random.choice(List2, 1000),
                 })
```

The output is:

```
      LeaseID  PropertyID  xyz  abc
0  NHQikWbUZI  phwUIn9IgZ    8   19
1  f6aBvrSeWe  zV0tmst212    9   15
2  hdTHtm7LvU  lC6uQJeHRX    8   14
3  FnppdLbbcq  na9dVUO3Ay    2   17
4  arXAq4EvzT  7dvKTclo6o    1   18
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative code:

Modified the function `gen_ids` in the question to return a `Series` instead.

```
# Import libraries
import random
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate alphanumeric lease id and property ids
def gen_ids(length, len_df):
    s = []
    for i in range(len_df):
        ids = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=length))
        s.append(ids)
    return s

# Create DataFrame
List1 = ['a','b','c','D','e']
List2 = ['G','h','k','L','q']
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'LeaseID': gen_ids(10, 1000),
                   'PropertyID': gen_ids(10, 1000),
                   'xyz': np.random.choice(List1, 1000),  
                   'abc': np.random.choice(List2, 1000)
                 })
```

Output

```
print(df)

        LeaseID  PropertyID xyz abc
0    gxpSTdLoPH  rswWVZuBIW   a   q
1    OSdR5vOA0I  gHKdcYKw5s   e   L
2    WAmNQ4ieRH  ThC1Apk5YA   e   h
3    BYUTgbKcbl  IKcdjvH9da   c   L
4    4CNFqbu7hO  uJEWhlEufu   a   k
..          ...         ...  ..  ..
```